# If statement(s) in lieu of a while loop

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop

This question is rather odd, however I had a friend ask if it was possible and I couldn't give him an answer. Would it be possible to write the following while-loop using if-statements instead?

```
while (!x.empty() && !y.empty()){}
```

I was thinking you could get around using a while-loop if you had a nested if-statement that set a flag maybe? Any other thoughts?

Sorry for the silly question.

Comment: Unless you have something like `goto`, probably not. A conditional statement is very different from a looping statement.

Comment: I'm unsure how to edit the question, however I am working with C++.

Could you technically rewrite a while-loop with a for-loop?

Comment: @Conman - You can always rewrite a while-loop as a for-loop. `for(;condition;){}` will create a for-loop with just a condition, and no initializer or expression.

Comment: You could use recursion instead, that would fit the requirements and cause a stack overflow depending on the amount of data

Answer (score 1):

You can use `break` statement inside `while` loop with if-else statement

```
while (1)
{
    if (!x.empty() && !y.empty()) 
    {
         // do something;
    }
    else break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat. you could do it with recursive function calls. like:

```
void whileLoop(){
   if(!(!x.empty() && !y.empty())){
      return;
   }

   //Code to run in loop here

   whileLoop();
}
```

you would call the function when you wanted to run the loop. notice the **not** sign in front of the condition you where checking for in the original loop; as if the condition is no longer true the loop code would not run.

Answer (score 0):

Another way: recursion

```
#include <stack>
#include <boost/hof.hpp>

int main()
{
    extern std::stack<int> get();

    auto x = get();
    auto y = get();

    auto f = boost::hof::fix([&](auto self)
    {
        if (!x.empty() && !y.empty())
        {
            x.pop();
            y.pop();
            self();
        }
        return 0;
    });

    boost::hof::result<int>(f)();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/M-JkV2

Answer (score 0):

Not directly, but another way without using `while`... a good ole `goto` statement..

```
int main()
{
    ....
start:
    if(!x.empty() && !y.empty())
        goto start;
    ....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compromise on code readability and achieve this with recursion. Beware that it will make the code more complex than it needs to be. Recursion would need more stack space than your regular iterative code. I'd do something like this -

```
//iterative
while (!x.empty() && !y.empty()) {
  //do something
}
```

```
//recursive
void recursion(vector<int> x, vector<int> y){
  if(!x.empty() && !y.empty()) {
    //do something

    //remove element from vector based on your condition

    x.pop_back();
    y.pop_back();
    recursion(x, y);
  } 
}
```

Exit condition for recursion is either of the vectors being empty.